# How to filter unix timestamp in Yii2 GridView?

Tags: unix, gridview, datepicker, yii2

I am using Kartik GridView and my date column setup is the following

```
    [
        'attribute'=>'created_date',
            'value' => function ($model, $index, $widget) {
            return Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_date);
        },
        'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.Y'],
        'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE,
        'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'autoclose' => true,
            'todayHighlight' => true,
        ]
        ],
        'width' => '160px',
        'hAlign' => 'center',
    ],
```

Search model

```
[['created_date'], 'safe'],

$query->andFilterWhere([
            'links_id' => $this->links_id,
            'modified_date' => $this->modified_date,
            'created_date' => $this->created_date,
        ]);
```

**created_date** is the column in the database that is generated automatically when record is created, which has the following format 
`2015-12-16 13:42:09.425618`.

Although date picker works I get SQL Error:

```
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links" LEFT JOIN "countries" ON "links"."country" = "countries"."country" WHERE "created_date"='2015-12-15'
```

So, how to properly filter unix timestamp with Yii2 kartik date picker?

Comment: What was the error ?

Comment: @ck_arjun Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "created_date" is ambiguous

Comment: Your links table and countries table.If both have "created_date" field you should specify table name along with field , wherever applicable.   "links.created_date" => $this->created_date

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks @ck_arjun. I figured this out. So in the search model the code should look like this

```
// Convert date to Unix timestamp
if (!empty($params['LinksSearch']['created_date'])) {
      $query->andFilterWhere([
        '(links.created_date::DATE)' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($params['LinksSearch']['created_date']))
      ]);
 }
```

This way you will be able to pass date in you own format to filter unix database column.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your grid view :

```
 [
        'attribute'=>'created_date',
            'value' => function ($model, $index, $widget) {
           $date = date('your date format eg.Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime($model->created_date);
            return date ;
        },
        'format' => ['date', 'php:d.m.Y'],
        'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_DATE,
        'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            'autoclose' => true,
            'todayHighlight' => true,
        ]
        ],
        'width' => '160px',
        'hAlign' => 'center',
    ],
```

Comment: Tried it but still get this error `The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links" LEFT JOIN "countries" ON "links"."country" = "countries"."country" WHERE "created_date"='2015-12-15'` . Also tried this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317351/yii2-datepicker-in-kartik-gridview-not-working but getting `The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "links" LEFT JOIN "countries" ON "links"."country" = "countries"."country" WHERE "created_date"=1450137600`

Answer (score 0):

In search model before return $dataProvider

insert code like next:

```
    if($this->created_normal)
    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'created_at', strtotime($this->created_normal), strtotime($this->created_normal)+86400]);
if($this->updated_normal)
    $query->andFilterWhere(['between', 'updated_at', strtotime($this->updated_normal), strtotime($this->updated_normal)+86400]);
```

updated_normal - help field in search model (yyyy-mm-dd)

Working is guaranted for int